# Python: Hint syntax that argument obeys both contracts simultaneously

Tags: python, type-hinting

I want to annotate my Python 3 code with type hints and struggle to find syntax for an *intersection type* (meaning object respects methods of all specified classes simultaneously).

Something like:

```
def func(ob: Type[A & B]):
    ob.canA()     # static type checker should allow methods from A & B
    ob.canB()     #
    ob.cannotC()  # but not from some other class C
```

You can see what is *intersection type* in the competing universe: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html

It mimics what I am familiar with (Java interfaces).

Note, I asked the same question here: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/lvp5c1/hint_syntax_that_argument_obeys_two_contracts/ and got only one irrelevant response about using an *union type* which is not an *intersection type*.

I cannot find anything useful in an official spec:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Following spec:

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/

says:

> We might add:
>
> - Intersection[t1, t2, ...]. Types that are subtype of each of t1, etc are subtypes of this. (Compare to Union, which has at least one instead of each in its definition.)

so it can be that intersection is not yet in the Python...

Comment: I don't see how you could get that to work without having to make a subclass that inherits from both `A` and `B` without that `Intersection` type being implemented any time soon.

Comment: Python's type system does not support intersection types

Comment: The best alternative you have is probably a Protocol